# Can I create a java class which can be used for all projects in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I want to create a simple Java Class file and access it from all my projects.

I know that I can do it by copy/paste metod but in that case the class file will be independent from its original source. Any changes I have made in the original class file will not effect the already copied ones into other projects.

Is there a way to link a class file in Android Studio?

Comment: Have a look into creating an Android library. There's plenty of documentation out there.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new library module in your project, proceed as follows:

```
Click File > New > New Module.
In the Create New Module window that appears, click Android Library, then click Next.

There's also an option to create a Java Library, which builds a traditional JAR file. While a JAR file is useful for many projects— especially when you want to share code with other platforms—it does not allow you to include Android resources or manifest files, which is very useful for code reuse in Android projects. So this guide focuses on creating Android libraries.
Give your library a name and select a minimum SDK version for the code in the library, then click Finish.
```

Once the Gradle project sync completes, the library module appears in the Project panel on the left. If you don't see the new module folder, make sure it's displaying the Android view.

Take a deeper look here https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

//edit

**Create the project**
Create new project
basic activity
next
Name: HelloWorld
package name: com.test.helloworld
API: 16
Language: JAVA

**Changed activity_main.xml to display centered text**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simpleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Creating the library module**
File/new/new module
android library
next
module-name: library
SDK: 16
Language: JAVA
finish
Gradle is automatically syncing

**Creating the test class**
I know I can make this string static but the OP requested a method
Notice I accidentally created the class inside of the test package of my module. It was unreachable

```
package com.test.library;

public class Library {

    public static String getDisplayText(){
        return "it worked";
    }
}
```

**Add my library to the main project**
Go to settings.gradle and ensure it included you module first
include ':library'
include ':app'
This was already done for me

Move over to build.gradle of the app module and add
include project(":library") at the top of your dependencies
I had to do this manually
Now resync with gradle

**Accessing the class**
This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.test.library.Library;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView simpleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.simpleTextView);
        simpleTextView.setText(Library.getDisplayText());

    }
}
```

It worked like a charm. Hope I could help you. Would be happy about an upvote

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have imported my module and I can see it in my project tree as a separate folder.  The quation now is that, how can I access the methods in the class file of  import3d module? There are many static methods in the class file of my module which I can see all of them when I click the class but cant access it from main project in the project tree.

Comment: Have you followed the entire instructions? Have you added you module as a dependency

Comment: Yes sure. Maybe the problem is that I dont know the correct syntax to access the methods in a Java class which is not in the same scope in project tree.I use "classname.methodname" syntax but it doesnt work.

Comment: That should work normally uf you're methods are static like you said. I would have to create a project and a libary myself because I never did it in android. I may have time at the evening to take a look at it. Make sure your gradle synced properly after adding the dependency.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope I could help